# Not Renaming Child Directory When Parent Directory is Renamed

Tags: find, directory, rename

My directory tree is like the following -

```
/media/blueray/Data/Test$ tree
.
├── What????
│   └── What????
└── What????.txt
```

When I run the command `find . -depth | rename 's/[?<>\\:*|\"]//g'`

It says -

```
Can't rename ./What????/What???? ./What/What: No such file or directory
```

However, after running the command, the directory structure becomes -

```
/media/blueray/Data/Test$ tree
.
├── What
│   └── What????
└── What.txt
```

It appears to me that `find` is starting to search from the top of the tree, so it is loosing track of the tree.

What is the solution here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem isn’t caused by `find`, it’s caused by `rename`: it’s processing the full path, so it tries to rename `./What????/What????` to `./What/What`, which fails because the `What` directory doesn’t exist (yet).

Getting `rename` to process filenames only, with `-d`, will fix this:

```
find . -depth | rename -d 's/[?<>\\:*|\"]//g'
```

If your version of `rename` doesn’t support the `-d` option (introduced with version 1.10 of `File::Rename`, assuming your `rename` is the Perl version), you can get `find` to pass the filenames only by running `rename` inside each directory:

```
find . -depth -execdir rename 's/[?<>\\:*|\"]//g' {} +
```

(Thanks to [Freddy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/332764/freddy) for [the solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/553728/find-deepest-first/553730?noredirect=1#comment1028232_553730).)

Comment: It says `Unknown option: d`

Comment: What’s the output of `rename -V`?

Comment: `/usr/bin/rename using File::Rename version 0.20`

Comment: @blueray Try `find . -depth -execdir rename 's/[?<>\\:*|\"]//g' {} +`

Comment: @Freddy Correct. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Freddy, I’ve added that to the answer. `-d` was added to `File::Rename` version 1.10.